# Azure DevOps: change the organization that owns the project

Tags: azure-devops, organization

I started to manage a project on azure DevOps by creating my personal organization. Now I should move the Project into an other organization that already exist, is this possible? or I need to recreate all board, etc ... from the beginning?
thank you to all for answers

Comment: Hi ,BMarck Do you try the migration tools to deal with your problem ? If you have any question ,please feel free to ask. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Now I should move the Project into an other organization that already
>   exist, is this possible?

For this issue, this is currently not supported in azure devops, there is no out-of-the-box feature in Azure devops to achieve it.

But this feature was planned to develop,there has been a such suggestion exist in it: [make it possible to move a Team Project between Team Project Collections](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365365/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1.html). You can comment and vote it there.

As a workaround, you can use some migration tools in the Visual Studio Marktplace, like [OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility) and [VSTS Copy Project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=canarysautomationspvtltd.vstscopyproject). These tool can help you to migrate Team Project within or across the collection. But is not full migration (only work items, test,source Control data etc.), each tool has its limitations.

Here is a [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/187412/vsts-to-vsts-migration-is-possible-now.html) that introduces several migration ways,please refer to it.